# Highlighting a field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting a bit stuck, I am trying to recreate the glow you get when you focus on a field in chrome even though my input box is made up for two parts.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/vAfxw/9/

Now this is what I was trying to do:

```
document.getElementById('location').onfocus=function(){
    this.value='';
    document.getElementById('searchContainer').style['border'] ='1px solid blue';
}

document.getElementById('location').onblur=function(){
    document.getElementById('searchContainer').style['border'] ='none';
}
```

Should I be surruonding my field and div with a "searchContainer" or should I instead by applying this CSS to both the field and the div? Basically I am trying to get the entire location box to glow blue when selected not just the input box.

Comment: If you're using jQuery why are you doing things like `document.getElementById('searchContainer').style['border'] ='1px solid blue';` instead of `$('#searchContainer').css('border','1px solid blue')`

Comment: Where is `searchContainer` or `field`? I could not find it anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: You're going to have some additional issues with styling this once you place a DIV in your code due to your CSS.  Since you are floating your controls you'll need to manually size the DIV and apply the CSS for the glow affect to it.  You do that to the form object if you are not putting anything else inside it.  Also you'll need to apply your function to all of the inputs.  If you are not using jQuery you can create a stand alone function and make it the handler on each of the inputs so you are only maintaining one function.

Comment: I am using jquery. Can you explain a bit about this function please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the CSS [Outline property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp).